# How to create a For Loop in cplex

Tags: loops, cplex

I am new to cplex. 
I would like to implement a loop for my MILP problem. It's about to add up.

For example like this:

time:   1 2 3 4
weight: 10 20 30 40

The solution should tell me the Summation weight at each time;

time: 1 2 3 4 
sum_weight: 10 30 60 100

I hope my problem becomes clear.

Comment: What API are you using? Are you using OPL? Is `time` a range and `weight` a decision variable array? Did you look at all of the examples that are included with CPLEX Optimization Studio?

Comment: I am using the OPL 12.9.0 in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization for win64.

Comment: time is a {int} and weight should be a decision variable Array. At the examples I can't find an example with loops.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use [IBM ILOG Script](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/opllanguser/topics/opl_languser_intro_scripting.html) (i.e., JavaScript). For example, the `foodmanufact` example has the following `execute` block at the end:

```
execute DISPLAY {   
  writeln(" Maximum profit = " , cplex.getObjValue());
  for (var i in Months) {
    writeln(" Month ", i, " ");
    write("  . Buy   ");
    for (var p in Products)
      write(Buy[i][p], "\t ");
    writeln();
    write("  . Use   ");
    for (p in Products) 
      write(Use[i][p], "\t ");
    writeln();
    write("  . store ");
    for (p in Products) 
      write(Store[i][p], "\t ");
    writeln();
  }
}
```

This can be modified to show the sum of `Buy` over products, like so:

```
execute DISPLAY {   
  writeln(" Maximum profit = " , cplex.getObjValue());
  for (var i in Months) {
    writeln(" Month ", i, " ");
    write("  . Buy   ");
    for (var p in Products)
      write(Buy[i][p], "\t ");
    writeln();
    // START: Display the sum of Buy over products:
    write("  . Sum(Buy)   ");
    var sumBuy = 0;
    for (var p in Products) {
        sumBuy += Buy[i][p];
        write(sumBuy, "\t ");            
    }
    writeln();
    // END
    write("  . Use   ");
    for (p in Products) 
      write(Use[i][p], "\t ");
    writeln();
    write("  . store ");
    for (p in Products) 
      write(Store[i][p], "\t ");
    writeln();
  }
}
```

This gives output, like the following:

```
Maximum profit = 100278.703703704

...

 Month 6 
  . Buy   480.37037037   629.62962963    0   730     0   
  . Sum(Buy)   480.37037037  1110    1110    1840    1840    
  . Use   0  200     0   230     20  
  . store 500    500     500     500     500
```

Comment: It is possible that this way only works if you have used a couple of tuple? In my skript I don't use tuples.